# Garbled display after Ubuntu upgrade to 2.6.32-2* kernel

Tags: graphics, 9.10

I was running Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic Koala) with no problems.  I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 10 (Lucid Lynx) and cannot use it normally.  After I log in, the screen scrambles (a purple/green mess)--impossible to see anything, although I can get out by marking the spot on the screen to click for a restart, so Linux is working behind the scenes.

If I start in recovery mode with basic graphics, I have no problems at all (other than limited functionality).  If I start the old 2.6.31-22 kernel, I see a bunch of "unmountable" errors in the startup script, but I can use Linux normally with no apparent problems.  I'm running an IBM ThinkPad A30 with ATI Mobility graphics.  Just to reiterate, the screen looks normal until I log in, at which point it goes bonkers.

What do I need to change in order to fix this?

Comment: Before upgrade did your have proprietary `fglrx` driver or `radeon`? If first, how did you install it?

Comment: I'm sure it's not proprietary--I just used all default drivers when I installed Ubuntu 9.

Answer (score 2):

and thanks.  The solution was actually a very simple update to the grub file, which I found in the release notes for 10.04.

> **Working around bugs in the new kernel video architecture**
>
> Ubuntu 10.04 LTS enables the new
>   kernel-mode-setting (KMS) technology
>   by default on most common video
>   chipsets. While this is a major step
>   forward for the graphics architecture
>   in Ubuntu, in some rare cases KMS will
>   prevent your video output from working
>   correctly, or from working at all. If
>   you need to disable KMS, you can do so
>   by booting with the nomodeset option.
>   You can also save this setting so that
>   it's applied at every boot by adding
>   it to your grub config

**For GRUB 2:** (The Default)

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and add
`nomodeset` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`.

Then run `sudo update-grub`;

**For GRUB 1:**

edit `/boot/grub/menu.lst` and add `nomodeset` to the line beginning with `# kopt=`,

Then run `sudo update-grub`).

I'm not sure what KMS does, but it sure screwed up my display.  Adding the "nomodeset" boot command fixed everything!